# How to add a shadow to a circular CSS image?

Tags: css, image, shadow

Trying to figure out how I add a shadow to 3 images I have central on my page, looks a little weird without one I believe.

At the moment my HMTL code for this is below:

```
<div id="imagesMain">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Cal\Photos\Gym.jpg" id="gym">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Cal\Photos\me.jpg" id="me">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Cal\Photos\NFL.jpg" id="nfl">
  </div>
```

and my CSS code for these images is also below:

```
#imagesMain {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  #imagesMain img {
    height: auto;
    width: 10%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
```

Thanks, Callum

Comment: `box-shadow` perhaps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this `filter: drop-shadow(1px 14px 5px rgb(14, 17, 17));` and adjust  the shadow according to your needs...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a box-shadow generator for CSS3.

[CSS3 box-shadow generator](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/)

You need to copy the box-shadow and add it to the image.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this! I have done that, however it seems to add the shadow to a background image? as in, my photo is there, but there's an oval behind my image much larger, that then has the shadow in it.

Comment: Thank you, I've removed the padding and now it works just fine. It was the padding stretching the shadow.

Comment: edit: sorted :) margin: 5rem seems to work for the spacing of the images, keeping them central.

Answer (score 0):

For images, I'd use a box-shadow property :

```
div {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}
```

The first two arguments are about the height/width of your shadow box, third argument is about the blurring effect and last one is the color of your shadow.

Comment: Thanks for this, it definitely shows the shadow now, however it seems to show the shadow on an oval image which stretches out behind my actual image, almost like a background..? not sure if I've maybe done something wrong with the code in regards to padding, or some other line..

Comment: It's probably because of your padding on img. Your image is well defined, but your actual image object is bigger than you imagine. You could use flexbox properties to evenly space your images in your div : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/